Reorder a string of length \$2^n\$ by permuting the \$n\$ binary digits of every index
Given a binary string \$s\$ of length \$2^n\$ and a permutation \$\sigma\$ of \$\{1,\dots,n\}\$, generate the binary string \$u\$ of length \$2^n\$ which is a reordering of \$s\$ such that \$u[i^\sigma]=s[i]\$ for each (\$0\$-based) index \$i\$, where \$i^\sigma\$ is obtained by \$\sigma\$-reordering the \$n\$ binary digits of \$i\$.
For example, \$110_b^{(23)}=101_b\$, so if \$\sigma\$ is the transposition \$(23)\$ then we need u[5] == s[6].
Note: we can think of \$s\$ as the truth table of an \$n\$-ary truth function, \$\sigma\$ as a reordering of the truth function's inputs, and \$u\$ as the truth table resulting from this reordering.
Full example: n=3, s=11010010, σ=(123) \$\to\$ u=10011100, because each index \$i=xyz_b\$ in \$s\$ maps to index \$zxy_b\$ in \$u\$, so we have
u[000] = s[000] = 1
u[001] = s[010] = 0
u[010] = s[100] = 0
u[011] = s[110] = 1
u[100] = s[001] = 1
u[101] = s[011] = 1
u[110] = s[101] = 0
u[111] = s[111] = 0

You can use any reasonable representation for \$\sigma\$ (e.g. a list \$[\sigma(1),\dots,\sigma(n)]\$ or cycle notation) and for \$s\$ (e.g. a bytestring, bigint, or list of booleans) and any standard input/output convention.

Now I'm wondering about a related problem--given a permutation of ${1, ..., 2^n}$, determining whether or not it corresponds to such a bit permutation! Actually, I suppose that should be as simple as transposing the bits of the indices and seeing if lexicographically sorting those gives $[0, ..., 2^n - 1]$.

@UnrelatedString how about: given two bit strings of length $2^n$, determine whether they differ by a permutation of this form.

Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4974317

Python + NumPy, 45 bytes
-5 thanks @att
lambda a,p:a.reshape(p*0+2).transpose(p).flat

Attempt This Online!
Expects the binary string and the permutation as NumPy arrays and returns a NumPy flatiter object.
How?
Quite literal approach: Arranges the input sequence into a 2x2x...x2 hypercube, shuffles dimensions according to permutation, and flattens the result.

if you're taking it as a numpy array 0*p+2

Uiua, 10 bytes
⊏⍜⊙⋯≡⊏¤⊙°⊏

Try it!
Takes input with the permutation as a 0-indexed array of indices, followed by the binary string.
⊏⍜⊙⋯≡⊏¤⊙°⊏
         ⊙°⊏ # create an array of indices
 ⍜⊙⋯        # convert to binary
      ≡⊏¤     # permute the bits
 ⍜⊙⋯        # convert back to numbers
⊏             # index into s


Charcoal, 16 bytes
⭆θ§θΣＥη∧＆κＸ²μＸ²λ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes s as the first input as a list or bitstring and σ as the second input as a list (or string if n<11) of 0-indexed destination indices and outputs a bitstring. Explanation:
 θ                  First input `s`
⭆                   Map over characters and join
   θ                First input `s`
  §                 Indexed by
      η             Second input `σ`
     Ｅ              Map over indices
         κ          Outer index
        ＆           Bitwise and
           ²        Literal integer `2`
          Ｘ         Raised to power
            μ       Source index
       ∧            Logical And
              ²     Literal integer `2`
             Ｘ      Raised to power
               λ    Destination index
    Σ               Take the sum
                    Implicitly print

(If you run this code on ATO instead of TIO then you can also pass σ as a dictionary mapping 0-indexed source indices to destination indices.)

Jelly, 7 bytes
UŒPṬỤỤị

Try it online!
Port of alephalpha's Nekomata answer.
U          Reverse p,
 ŒP        shortest-first powerset,
   Ṭ       untruth (surprised this vectorizes!),
    ỤỤ     double grade up (convert to permutation),
      ị    index into s.

Jelly, 9 8 bytes
ịⱮL2ṗɗỤị

Try it online!
Pretty naive implementation. Takes a 1-indexed permutation list \$[\sigma(1), ..., \sigma(n)]\$ on the left, and the string \$s\$ on the right.
   2ṗ       Raise [1, 2] to the Cartesian power of
  L         the length of the permutation (= n),
ịⱮ   ɗ      and index the permutation into each result.
      Ụ     Grade that up (argsort),
       ị    and index into s.


APL(Dyalog Unicode), 22 10 bytes SBCS
Same idea as @Albert.Lang's.
∊⊣⍉2⍨¨⍤⊣⍴⊢

Try it on APLgolf!
Try it on APLgolf! 22bytes
BQN, 8 bytes
⥊⊣⍉2˙¨⊸⥊

Try it on BQNPAD

Nekomata, 6 bytes
↔SĦaõ@

Attempt This Online!
Takes the permutation as a 0-indexed list, e.g., [1,2,0] for \$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&2\\1&2&0\end{pmatrix}\$. Takes the binary string as a list of integers, e.g., [1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0] for 11010010.
↔SĦaõ@         Take [1,2,0] [1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0] as an example
↔           Reverse
                -> [0,2,1]
 S          Find a subset
                -> [] [0] [2] [0,2] [1] [0,1] [2,1] [0,2,1]
  Ħ         Histogram
                -> [] [1] [0,0,1] [1,0,1] [0,1] [1,1] [0,1,1] [1,1,1]
   a        All possible values
                -> [[],[1],[0,0,1],[1,0,1],[0,1],[1,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]]
    õ       Ordering
                -> [0,2,4,6,1,3,5,7]
     @      Index into the second input
                -> [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]


K (ngn/k), 14 bytes
Naive implementation. It takes \$\sigma\$ as a 0-indexed premutation vector.
{y@2/(2\!#y)x}

Try it online!

Python3, 113 bytes
lambda n,s,o:''.join(s[int(''.join(x for _,x in sorted([*zip(o,bin(j)[2:].zfill(n))])),2)]for j in range(len(s)))

Try it online!

188. Also not sure you really need the join or the [0]; output format is pretty lenient.

@UnrelatedString Thank you, updated

oh, 108

*107 (and I'd still maintain that you can go down to 100 without the outer join)

*103

(and I guess another -6 taking $2^n$ instead of $n$, which OP seems to approve of/encourage)

Python, 113 110 bytes
lambda s,p,n:[s[i]for i in g(range(n),*p[::-1])]
g=lambda s,h,*t:sorted(t and g(s,*t)or s,key=lambda i:i>>h&1)

-3 thanks to Karl
Attempt This Online!
Probably golfable and loses to a more direct approach, but this one is just too much fun. (2*&ÞƒJ’$}‘ị for 11 in Jelly--thanks 1-indexing...) Takes an inverse 0-indexed permutation list \$[\sigma^{-1}(0 ),...,\sigma^{-1}(n-1)]\$, where the inverse is equivalently the grade-up, alongside \$2^n\$.
Since sorted is stable, this sorts by each bit in permutation order, essentially "bubbling" that bit to most significant (w.r.t. the destination indices) before being "pushed down" by the next.
A little more digestible:
lambda s,p,n:[s[i]for i in reduce(lambda x,h:sorted(x,key=lambda i:i>>h&1),p,range(n))]
from functools import*


Took me a few minutes, but I get it! Amusing way to do a recursive reduce by "destructuring the varargs". functools.reduce(lambda s,h: sorted(s,key=lambda i:i>>h&1), p[::-1], range(n))

@Karl I've actually seen this done so many times that I assumed it was shorter than importing functools without even trying that... and I was right for the most part, but given that it also obviates the need to reverse p, they actually tie! Also didn't occur to me to take $2^n$ as input (too Jelly-brained), so that saves 3 bytes on both.
